# Anycast in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless

Ubuntu 18.04 is installed in my Acer laptop; I have "Anycast" dongle and a Samsung TV with HDMI port. How can I mirror my laptop screen on the TV ? Can you please describe the method step by step ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you finish it? Could you please advise me the way